# Inverse MixColumns AES Rijndael algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, encryption, rijndael

I am currently writing a AES implementation in c and I am having issues computing the inverse of the MixColumn. My function is recursive as that's what made the most sense when figuring out how to do the multiplication and addition for 09, 0E, 0D and 0B mod x^4 + 1.

```
unsigned char multiplyByte(unsigned char c, unsigned char f){
    unsigned char result = 0;
    if(f==1){
        return c;
    }else if(f==2){
        return = c << 1;
    }else if(f & 1){
        return multiplyByte(((c << 1) ^ c) ^ ((c & 0x80) >> 7 ? 0x1b : 0x00), f/2);
    }else{
        return multiplyByte((c << 1) ^ ((c & 0x80) >> 7 ? 0x1b : 0x00), f/2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

c is the byte being multiplied and f is the factor.

I am trying to get this to make sense on paper with the values 0x47 for c and 0x0E for f. Using the answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-does-one-implement-the-inverse-of-aes-mixcolumns) and the tables [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns). If I work this answer out on paper I get...

0x47 x 0x0E:

(((((X x 2) + X) x 2) + X) x 2)

Where addition is simply XOR, then this should be equivalent to..

0x47 x 0x03 = (0x47 << 1 XOR 47) = 0xC9

So,

(((0xC9 x 2) + 0xC9) x 2) = 0x47 x 0x0E =

(0x40) x 2 = 0x80.

However, I am expecting 0x87 as per the tables in the second link.

Comment: You substituted 0xC9 in the rest of the formula instead of the original 0x47. 0x47 * 3 is equal to 0xc9. So the rest of the formula is (((0xc9 *2) + 0x47)*2 = (0x89 + 0x47) * 2 = 0xce * 2 = 0x87.

Comment: So if thats the case then recursion doesn't seem to be best option to me anymore. What do you think? @JamesKPolk